# Wireshark: what does the tilde (~) operator mean in display filters?

Tags: wireshark, packet-capture

I use a lot of wireshark at work. Last week, a customer sent me a screenshot showing a tilde in the display filter. I tried it myself and it works (the filter shows as valid) but I'm not sure of what it does. For example:

```
ip.dst_host ~ 10.10
```

I read the [documentation](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsug_html_chunked/ChWorkBuildDisplayFilterSection.html), [man page](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/man-pages/wireshark-filter.html) and the [wiki](https://wiki.wireshark.org/DisplayFilters) but didn't find any info on this operator.

From what I've tested, it appears to work as *"contains"* but I have no way of knowing.

Does anyone know what it means? A link to a source would also be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tilde character, `~`, is a shortcut for the `matches` operator as can be seen in the [scanner.l](https://code.wireshark.org/review/gitweb?p=wireshark.git;a=blob;f=epan/dfilter/scanner.l;h=8f5f96a25d2364396ad712e0b6c485c5100ad0bf;hb=HEAD#l158) file.  Since Wireshark doesn't document this anywhere, I would suggest opening a [Wireshark bug report](https://bugs.wireshark.org/bugzilla/enter_bug.cgi) asking for it to be documented.

Comment: Nice answer. Bug open and confirmed: https://bugs.wireshark.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=13320. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: For anyone following the bug, it has been fixed, meaning that the `~` operator has been documented in the wireshark-filter man page, the user guide and the wiki.  The documentation changes may or may not be back-ported, and if not, it will only be available with the next Wireshark release, which will be Wireshark 2.4, likely to be released sometime around Sharkfest '17.  The actual release date will be posted on the [Wireshark LifeCycle][1] wiki page when it is known.[1]: https://wiki.wireshark.org/Development/LifeCycle